# Pasar parametros de componentes a Context

Tags: reactjs

Necesito pasarle un parametro que va a ser el pageNumber desde el componente al context para que el pageNumber se pueda usar en el context
para que en el context pueda hacer el fetch a la API con el correspondiente numero que le paso el componente

Codigo del Context:

```
import { useQuery } from '@tanstack/react-query';
export const PhotosContext = createContext()

function AppContextProvider(props) {
    const pageNumber = 1

    const {isLoading, data:fotos, isError, error} = useQuery({queryKey: ["fotos"], queryFn: async () => {
        return await fetch(`http://127.0.0.1:5000/api-content/images/${pageNumber}`)
        .then((response) => response.json())
        }, 
        staleTime: 300 * 1000 // cache data for 300 seconds
        });


    return (
        <PhotosContext.Provider value={{
            fotos,
            isLoading,
            }}>
            {props.children}
        </PhotosContext.Provider>
    );
}

export default AppContextProvider;
```

y este es el codigo del componente:

```
import Products from './products';
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import Navbar from './Views/Navbar';
import Spinner from './Views/Sppiner';
import { PhotosContext } from '../context/Appcontext';


function TaskFotos(){
    const {pageNumber} = useParams();
    const {fotos,isLoading} = useContext(PhotosContext)

    if (isLoading) return <Spinner />   
    return(
    <>
    <Navbar/>
    <div className="bg-white">
        <div className="mx-auto max-w-2xl px-4 py-16 sm:px-6 sm:py-24 lg:max-w-6xl lg:px-4">
            <h2 className="text-3xl text-center font-bold tracking-tight text-gray-900">Products</h2>
            <div className="mt-6 grid grid-cols-1 gap-x-6 gap-y-10 sm:grid-cols-2 lg:grid-cols-3 xl:gap-x-24">
            {fotos?.map((foto, index) => (
                    <Products id={foto?.id} image={foto?.image} name={foto?.name} price={foto?.price} key={index}/>
            ))} 
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </>
    );
}

export default TaskFotos;
```

En la documentacion no aparece nada(por lo que vi) y GPT me tiro cualquier cosa.

Alguna sugerencia? desde ya muchas gracias.

Comment: ¿En que momento piensas cambiar el pageNumber? veo que estas mostrando una lista de productos que vienen en la pagina 1.

Comment: Si, esta envuelta la app con el provider

Comment: Esa es la pregunta, no se como pasarle el pageNumber cuando cambie la pagina

Comment: Bien entonces muestras la página con los elementos de página 1 y el usuario debe de alguna forma pasar a la siguiente página, ¿Este cambio de página lo vas a hacer con un boton, infinite scroll cual es la idea a nivel UI? poque parece que la pagina viende desde useParams,  si pudieras mostrar la implementacion de esa ruta

Comment: La idea a nivel UI es que si el usuario quiere cambiar de pagina en la parte baja tiene unos botones para cambiar a la pagina 1,2,3 o 4 eso mediante un <a> que redirije a la pagina con su numero correspondiente por ejemplo: products/2/ que eso lo toma el useparams

Comment: La ruta es la siguiente `<Route path="/products/:numberOfPage" element={<TaskFotos />} />` y este es un ejemplo del boton `<a href='/products/1' className="btn btn-blue mx-2">1</a>`

Answer (score 0):

Comparto el siguiente ejemplo

---

Puedes adaptarlo a tu proyecto ( agregar useQuery), en general se debe usar una funcion de **retro-propagación (sale del componente y regresa causando un re-render)**, aqui la función tiene el nombre de `setPageNumber`.

Notese como se declara y **sale** desde el `provider` para poder ser consumida por `useContext` en tu `Child` component `TaskFotos`, desde ahí **regresa** y causa un re-render al actualizar el estado de `page` y se obtienen los datos de la nueva página para ser renderizados :

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, createContext, useContext } from "react";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Routes,
  Route,
  Link,
  useNavigate
} from "react-router-dom";

const DataContext = createContext(null);

function ItemList() {
  const { data, setPageNumber, page, totalPages } = useContext(DataContext);
  console.log(data);
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Items</h2>
      <ul>
        {data.map((item) => (
          <li key={item.id}>{item.title}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
      <div>
        <button disabled={page === 1} onClick={() => setPageNumber(page - 1)}>
          Previous
        </button>
        <button
          disabled={page === totalPages}
          onClick={() => setPageNumber(page + 1)}
        >
          Next
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [page, setPage] = useState(1);
  const [totalPages, setTotalPages] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts?_page=${page}`)
      .then((response) => {
        setTotalPages(Number(response.headers.get("X-Total-Count")));
        return response.json();
      })
      .then((data) => setData(data))
      .catch((error) => console.log(error));
  }, [page]);

  const setPageNumber = (pageNumber) => {
    setPage(pageNumber);
  };

  return (
    <DataContext.Provider value={{ data, setPageNumber, page, totalPages }}>
      <div>
        <nav>
          <Link to="/">Home</Link>
          <Link to="/items">Items</Link>
        </nav>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<h1>Home</h1>} />
          <Route path="/items" element={<ItemList />} />
        </Routes>
      </div>
    </DataContext.Provider>
  );
}

function Main() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <App />
    </Router>
  );
}

export default Main;
```